# How to find minimum radius of convergence for the following equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I was asked to find minimum radius of convergence of the solution for this differential equation around point $x_0=-1$:
$$(5x^2+x+\frac{1}{4})y''+\frac{x+2}{x-a}y'+\frac{1}{2x+3}y=0 $$I know how to calculate **minimum radius of convergence** and that can be calculated as:$$|x-x_0|<R$$such that $x$ is defining nearest singular point. We know that from the equation$$x\in\{\frac{2i-1}{10},\frac{-2i-1}{10},\frac{-3}{2},a\}$$but how to define **nearest singular point** when one of them ($a$) is not defined?

Comment: The closest to $x_0=-1$ excepting $a$ is $-\frac32$, so you get $R=\min(|a+1|,\frac12)$. There is not much further that you can do with the given data.